# Navigation Controller behaviour in swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have LoginViewController as my initial view controller. I am going to MainviewController after login. I don't want to put LoginViewController in navigationController because when I am logging our from MainViewController, it is showing me my previous login details filled in login screen. How do I add view controller to avoid this scenario. I don't want to see the previous data in loginView Controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid this scenario by following 2 ways:

1. After successful login, in `viewDidDisappear` you can clear the text from textfield.
2. Set your rootview controller as `MainViewController` after login is done.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your `LoginViewController` in a `UINavigationController` and push `MainViewController` when the user logs in.

To avoid the problem of “showing me my previous login details filled in login screen”, you should override `viewDidDisappear:` in `LoginViewController` to clear out the details. For example:

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var usernameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var passwordField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        usernameField.text = ""
        passwordField.text = ""
    }
```